# How to regenerate WordPress thumbnails via Bash?

Tags: wordpress, bash, thumbnails

Our website has a lot of images (around 30.000). I'm looking for a way to regenerate all thumbnails, as our website's layout has changed. Using a plugin is not reliable as it requires a browser.

So, is there any way to regenerate all thumbnails via BASH?

NOTE: the images should have the following sizes: 630x290 and 960x495. Images should be center-cropped.

Answer (score 5):

You could use imagemagick's convert.

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#resize

As example use of it in a bash script is this:

```
while IFS= read -r FILE; do
    echo convert "$FILE" -resize "630x290" "${FILE%.???}.630x290.jpg"
    echo convert "$FILE" -resize "960x495" "${FILE%.???}.960x495.jpg"
done < <(find -type f -iname '*.jpg')
```

Remove echo when you think it's the right command already.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know about BASH,
but you can regenerate your post thumbnails without any plugin, just put the below code in your theme functions.php

```
add_action('image_save_pre', 'add_image_options');
function add_image_options($data){
    global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;
    foreach($_wp_additional_image_sizes as $size => $properties){
        update_option($size."_size_w", $properties['width']);
        update_option($size."_size_h", $properties['height']);
        update_option($size."_crop", $properties['crop']);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want to use the browser, so your solution doesn't answer the Question. Also, the only difference between using this code in `functions.php` or in a custom plugin is that the first option is a bad practice: see [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615)